# Adding image to UIActivityViewController in iOS7 takes twitter characters

Tags: ios7, ios7.1

I'm using the `UIActivityViewController` to allow users to share to both Facebook and/or Twitter. I have a common string shared for sharing to both Facebook and Twitter.

```
NSMutableArray *postItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSString *message = @"Text removed for confidentiality reasons";
[postItems addObject:message];
[postItems addObject:[NSURL URLWithString:@"linktoappstore"]];
[postItems addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"appicon"]];

//Included to show this is initialized before adding to UIActivityViewController, even though this isn't part of the issue with Twitter sharing.
MailActivity *mailActivity = [[MailActivity alloc] init];

UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:postItems applicationActivities:@[mailActivity]];
```

The issue is when I add the `UIImage` to the array. Doing so shows the image in both iOS 6 and 7, but in 7 it increases my tweet character count by 23. In iOS 6, it doesn't affect it at all. This is making so that the tweet message is 12 characters too long in iOS7 while I have 11 characters of wiggle room in iOS6. Anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone running into this issue, what was happening in iOS6 is that it was actually dropping the URL attached when the character count exceeded the limit. iOS7 is calculating the limit correctly. This seems like a huge bug to randomly drop your link if your character count is too high.